# Soql Injection in dynamic query in checkmarx Scanner report

Tags: soql-injection

My Apex class for dynamic query is

```
if(!String.isEmpty(SearchGrpName))
 SearchGrpNum = '\'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(GrpNumZ.trim()) + '%\'';
  whereClause += 'Accountnumber like ' +SearchGrpNum+' and '; 
  }           
 }
  if(!String.isEmpty(SearchGrpName))
  {
  SearchGrpName = '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SearchGrpName.trim())+'%\'';
  whereClause += 'Name like ' +SearchGrpName+' and ';
  }
 if(!String.isEmpty(SearchGrpYr) && sgrpnm != 'Y')
  {
   SearchGrpYr = '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SearchGrpYr.trim())+'\'';
   whereclause += 'HBC_Grp_Yr__c = ' +SearchGrpYr ;
  }

 whereClause = whereClause.removeEnd(' and ');
 if(!String.isEmpty(whereClause))
 {
      queryString = 'select id,AccountNumber,Name,Type from Account where '+whereClause   +  ' LIMIT :LimitSize OFFSET :OffsetSize' ;   
      acctlist = Database.query(queryString); 
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting

**SOQL SOSL Injection result path 4:**
Object: searchgrpnum in file: /classes/GroupSearch.cls

L 82: whereClause += 'Accountnumber like ' +SearchGrpNum+' and ';

Object: whereclause in file: /classes/GroupSearch.cls

L 106: whereClause = whereClause.removeEnd(' and ');

Object: whereclause in file: /classes/GroupSearch.cls

L 111: String querystring = 'select id,AccountNumber,Name,Type from Account where '+whereClause   +  ' LIMIT :LimitSize OFFSET :OffsetSize' ;

Object: query in file: /classes/GroupSearch.cls

L 112: acctlist = Database.query(query);

**SOQL SOSL Injection result path 5:**
Similarity Id: -37089001
Object: searchgrpname in file: /classes/GroupSearch.cls

L 88: whereClause += 'Name like ' +SearchGrpName+' and ';

Object: whereclause in file: /classes/GroupSearch.cls

L 106: whereClause = whereClause.removeEnd(' and ');

Object: whereclause in file: /classes/GroupSearch.cls

L 111: String querystring = 'select id,AccountNumber,Name,Type from Account where '+whereClause   +  ' LIMIT :LimitSize OFFSET :OffsetSize' ;

Object: query in file: /classes/GroupSearch.cls

L 112: acctlist = Database.query(query);

I'm escaping the singlequotes everywhere but still getting the soql injections. Help Please

Comment: Have you tried to debug the queryString variable? What does it say before firing Database.query?

Comment: It results all the related search results.I'm not facing any issues in this. But when i run checkmarx scanner getting SoQl injection error

Comment: which line in the code checkmarx reporting as issue?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not using escaping everywhere. `SearchGrpNum` is not escaped at

`whereClause += 'Accountnumber like ' +SearchGrpNum+' and ';`

similarly, the where clause at

```
queryString = 'select id,AccountNumber,Name,Type from Account where '+whereClause   +  ' LIMIT :LimitSize OFFSET :OffsetSize' ;
```

You must use escape single quote in each concatenation. Practically, this is not needed but, Checkmarx rules will consider it as injection threat.

**Solution:-**
Instead of using String concatenation, use [Apex variable reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm). Below I am trying to give example:-

```
  if(!String.isEmpty(SearchGrpName))
      SearchGrpNum = '\'%' + GrpNumZ.trim() + '%\'';
      whereClause += 'Accountnumber like :SearchGrpNum and '; 
    }           
  }
  if(!String.isEmpty(SearchGrpName))
  {
     SearchGrpName = '\'' + SearchGrpName.trim()+'%\'';
     whereClause += 'Name like :SearchGrpName and ';
  }
  if(!String.isEmpty(SearchGrpYr) && sgrpnm != 'Y')
  {
     SearchGrpYr = '\'' + SearchGrpYr.trim()+'\'';
     whereclause += 'HBC_Grp_Yr__c =:SearchGrpYr' ;
  }

 whereClause = whereClause.removeEnd(' and ');
 if(!String.isEmpty(whereClause))
 {
      queryString = 'select id,AccountNumber,Name,Type from Account where '+String.escapeSingleQuotes(whereClause)   +  ' LIMIT :LimitSize OFFSET :OffsetSize' ;   
      acctlist = Database.query(queryString); 
 }
```

Note: *You may need to tweak the solution a little bit as I didn't compile.*